# Get count of rows from joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

Table1: users

| id | name | faculty_id | level_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | mark | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | sam | 1 | 2 |

Table 2: subjects

| id | title | faculty_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | physics | 1 |
| 2 | chemistry | 1 |
| 3 | english | 2 |

SQL query:

```
SELECT count(subjects.id) FROM users INNER JOIN subjects ON users.faculty_id = subjects.faculty_id WHERE users.level_id = 1
```

I'm trying to get count of subjects where `users.level_id = 1`, Which should be 2 in this case `physics` and `chemistry`.

But it's returning more than 2.

Why is that and how to get only 2?

Comment: I think, you are trying to get count based on faculty_id and level_id. Select count(id) from subjects INNER JOIN users on subjects.faculty_id = users.level_id group by users.level_id; You may not need group by statement though

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `exists`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM subjects s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM users u
              WHERE u.faculty_id = s.faculty_id AND
                    u.level_id = 1
             );
```

This counts subjects where a user exists with a level of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are joining users and subjects on faculty_id; this produces every combination of user and subject rows (2 users and 2 subjects makes 4 combined rows); change your query to `SELECT users.*, subjects.* FROM...` to see how this works.

`count(subjects.id)` counts the number of non-null subjects.id values in your results; you can just do `count(distinct subjects.id)`.

Answer (score 1):

The two tables are not directly related as none is parent to the other. The faculty table is parent to both tables and this is what relates the two tables indirectly.

When joining the faculties' students with the faculties' subjects per faculty, you get all combinations (john|physics, mark|physics, sam|physics, john|chemistry, mark||chemistry, ...). Whether John really has the subject Physics cannot even be gathered from the database. We see that John studies a faculty containing the subjects Physics and Chemistry, but does every student have every subject belonging to their faculty? You probably know but we don't. That shows that in order to write proper queries, one should know their database :-)

Now you are joining the tables and get all students per faculty multiplied with all subjects per faculty. You limit this to level_id = 1, which gets you 2 students x 2 subjects = 4. You could use `COUNT(*)` for this, because you are counting rows. By applying `COUNT(subjects.id)` instead you are only counting rows for which the subject ID is not null, but that is true for all rows, because all four combined rows have either subject ID 1 (Physics) or 2 (Chemistry). Counting something that cannot be null makes no sense, except for counting distinct, as has already been suggested. You can `COUNT(DISTINCT subjects.id)` to get the distinct number of subjects matching yur conditions.

This, however, has two drawbacks. First, the query doesn't clearly show your intention. Why do you join all students with all subjects, when your are not really interested in the (four) combinations? Secondly, you are building an unnecessary intermediate result (four rows in your small example) that must be searched for duplicates, so these can be removed from the counting. That means more memory consumed and more work for the DBMS.

What you want to count is subjects. So select from the subjects table. Your condition is that a student exists with level 1 for the same faculty. Conditions belong in the `WHERE` clause. Use `EXISTS` as Gordon suggests in his answer or use `IN` which is slightly shorter to write and may hence be considered a tad more readable (but that boils down to personal preference, as `EXISTS` and `IN` express exactly the same thing here).

```
select count(*)
from subjects
where faculty_id in (select faculty_id from users where level_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add "distinct" before subjects.id

your SQL query like:

```
SELECT count(distinct subjects.id) FROM users INNER JOIN subjects ON users.faculty_id = subjects.faculty_id WHERE users.level_id = 1
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Don't build an intermediate result larger than you need. This is more memory consumed and more work to do for the DBMS. It doesn't make a difference with 4 vs. 2 rows, but it can make a huge difference with more data. Whenever you need `DISTINCT` ask yourself what makes this necessary. If it's really the data okay (but this is rarely the case), if it's your joins (which is more common), change that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count level_id and you have mentioned subject_id in the code. I would suggest first join two tables.

```
SELECT users.name, users.level_id, 
subjects.title 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN subjects ON 
users.faculty_id = subjects.faculty_id  as new_table
```

After joining the table u can get the count.

```
SELECT level_id, COUNT(level_id) 
FROM new_table 
GROUP BY level_id 
WHERE level_id = 1
```

(You have not mentioned group by in your code.)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the requiest. Your solution would still get a count of 4 for level 1 and not 2 (subjects) as the OP wants. Moreover, you have a typo in your second query. `WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY`. And as `level_id` cannot be null, you should not `COUNT(level_id) `, but rather `COUNT(*)` directly in order to indicate that you are counting rows and not to give the DBMS unnecessary work (looking out for nulls to omit from the counting).